# R Programming, How do I check if a number contains a last digit of 1?

Tags: r

For example I need to find the sum of all prime numbers between 1000 and 2000 that have a last digit of 1.

So far I have :

```
sum(primes[primes >=1000 & primes <= 2000])
```

Comment: Look at the remainder mod 10?

Comment: Adding to @John Coleman's answer: primes[primes %% 10 == 1] gives those with mod 1

Comment: So I got the answer with `sum(primes[primes >=1000 & primes <= 2000 & primes %% 10 == 1]) `, but I dont quite understand how Modulus plays a role in this (It has been a while since I used them).

Comment: 81 divided by 10 has a quotient of 8 and a remainder of 1. Similarly 57 divided by 10 leaves a remainder of 7. It is exactly this remainder that `%%` computes.

Comment: %% is correctly called as modulo operator a classic example of which is our clocks. Numbers repeat themselves after a certain number. Modulus is sometimes referred to absolute value only

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(primes[primes >=1000 & primes <= 2000 & primes %% 10 == 1])
```